# How to translate "He's not as young now as he was then"?

Tags: grammaire, traduction, comparatifs

I'm not looking for an expression with the same meaning, I'm looking to understand the grammar necessary for this sentence.

Here is my weak attempt:

> Il n'est pas aussi jeune maintenant qu'il était à cette époque.

I would also like to reverse it-- "He was younger then than he is now."

> Il était plus jeune à cette époque qu'il est maintenant.

Comment: I would translate it like that : "*Il n'est plus aussi jeune qu'il était.*". And your second sentence : "*Il était plus jeune dans le temps.*" or "*Il était plus jeune à l'époque*". (I think it is already explicit that the it is referring to the present time.)

Comment: *dans le temps* == "at the time" ? I thought it was ... I don't know, *en ce temps* or *a/en ce moment*. I also keep trying to use *lors* in here somewhere.

Comment: http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-french/at%20the%20time

Comment: I used "*dans le temps*" in a similar way I would of used "*dans le passé*" (*in the past*).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Il n'est plus aussi jeune qu'il ne l'était*.

In this sentence *ne … plus* expresses “not anymore” (it's the most natural translation for the *now*), and *aussi … que* expresses “as … as”.

In the last part of the sentence, *ne* is a *ne explétif* (i.e. not a real negation) which is commonly found in comparison bases (this particular expletive *ne* is considered mandatory by most). And *le* stands for the previous attribution “jeune”.

The suggested “reverse” sentence lacks the above-mentioned *ne* and *le*, but sounds idiomatic otherwise: *Il était plus jeune à cette époque qu'il ne l'est maintenant.*

Comment: Argh I under-utilise *ne...plus* so badly. Need to start incorporating it into my French thoughts more.

Comment: So, I remember that *plus* is pronounced without the *s* in a negative context like this-- but that's overridden by the need for a liaison here, right?

Comment: Yes, a z-liaison is common here.